# I can see the posted data in the url but nothing happen

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

its been 2 days that im stuck with this error i can see the data that i post but the next page do not load
when i submit i get  http://localhost:8000/android/www/login1.html?username=**********&password=****************&action=SignIn
thanks for ur help.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('button[type=submit]').submit(function () {

            var username = $('input[name=username]').val();
            var password = $('input[name=password]').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost/server1/login1.php",
                data: $('#login').serialize(),

              dataType: 'json',
               success:function(json){

                    if(json.status === 'success') {
                        alert('Tout est bon');
                        window.location.href="TestPorteur.html";

                    }

                    else{
                        window.location.href="ResetPassword.html";
                    }

                }

             /* */
            });
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

```html
<div class="login-bottom" id="login">
        <form id="form" >
            <div class="text">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Numéro Téléphone" id="username" name="username" />
                <span class="men"></span>
                <div class="clear"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password..." id="password" name="password" />
                <span class="pass"></span>
                <div class="clear"> </div>
            </div>

            <div class="remember">
                <div class="remember-top">
                    <a href="#">Mot de passe oublié?</a>

                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="send">
                    <button type="submit" id="action" name="action" value="SignIn">Sign In</button>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"> </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

```css
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
 include('conn.php');

 if(isset($_POST["username"])&& isset($_POST["password"])){
   $password = $_POST['password'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
 
  echo"Veuillez remplir les champs";
}


 $sql7="select * from utilisateur WHERE username='$username'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql7);
while($result1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 $var=$result['password'];}
  
  

if($password!='$var'){
 $status="passworderrone";
echo json_encode(['status' => $status]);
  
 }



if($password=='$var'){
   
   

$vari='11';


function getRemoteIp(){ 
    if( !ini_get('register_globals') ) { 
            return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
    } else { 
        return @$REMOTE_ADDR; 
    } 
 
    return ""; 
}

$ip = getRemoteIp();
$sql2="select * from session WHERE username='$username'";
$usrname=mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($usrname)){
 $vari=$result['username'];
 
  }
if('$vari'==$username){
 $status= "dejainscris";
 echo json_encode(['status' => $status]);
 $sql3 = "INSERT INTO session (username, tps_connx, tcpip)
VALUES ('$username',NOW(),'$ip')";

$res3=mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
 
}

else {$status="premiereinscription";
echo json_encode(['status' => $status]);
}
}


?>
```

Comment: Possible that the form is being submitted without the jQuery being run at all meaning ajax isn't being used? Simple debugging - add `console.log('Submit function called');` and see if that logs in the browser console. If it doesn't then try adding `event.preventDafault();` to your submit function, this will stop the forms default behaviour submitting.

Comment: thank u newtojs4 but  i got nothing when i did in the console

Comment: Then your form is being submitted before the jQuery can run. Well you have a few options. you can use `event.preventDefault();` in your function or `return false;` to stop the form being submitted.

Comment: i have already a return false; in my script!! and event.preventDefault(); doesn't work.

Comment: I have just noticed you are targeting the submit button. `$('button[type=submit]').submit(function () {` Try targeting the form since the form has the action of submitting...? `$('#form').submit(function () {`

Comment: that what i had but when i did that i dont get the data in the url

Comment: You don't want anything in the url! When you see those parameters in the URL it's because your page has just reloaded "trying to send that data" the point of ajax is to keep the client on the page with no reload while making a request. I suggest you start placing some `console.log();` in your source code, open the console and debug. Example: Check the ajax for the response? `success:function(json){
console.log(json);`

Comment: as u can see in the code php i return status so in javascript it deppend on the value of status i want to send the user to another interface i did that before and its working

Comment: Yes... and have you checked what the PHP is returning back to your ajax request?

Comment: when i run the php code with real values (password and username) it work

Comment: I mean have you checked it within ajax... Just like I have posted above. When using javacript/jQuery use your browser console, it's your best friend! Check it for any error reports and use `console.log('Some success message');` to check parts of your function are working, you can also use it to display values/data. Check the ajax response.

Comment: im sorry i did console.log(json);  but nothing  happened  :(

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console? place a `console.log()` at the start of your function. make sure the function is running first.

Comment: yes i did that nothing happen in the console!

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do to fix this.

1. Remove `type=submit` from button and in JS instead of catching submit event, you should catch click event.

   `<button id="action" name="action" value="SignIn">Sign In</button>`

   and in JS you should look for `click` event.

   `$('button#action').click(function () {`

   The reason for this `type=submit` directly submit the form. So first that needs to be checked, then look for click event and do your thing.
2. Second way to do this is that instead of catching submit event on button, look for submit event on form because it is meant for forms.

   so your JS should

   `$('#form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ...`